# Is it adviceable to use GOTO Statement in Catch block of SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

Create Procedure `proc1` 
AS 
BEGIN 
Lab1: 
Begin Try 
--Select Statements Logic 
End Try 
Begin Catch 
GOTO Lab1 
End Catch 
End

Comment: In NO language is GOTO advisable.

Comment: As currently written it will potentially cause an infinite loop if the error condition is permanent

Comment: @SMor you wouldn't get very far working in Commodore Basic V2 ;-)

Comment: Please don't ask questions which have this low quality.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you expect us to be helpful, please invest the bare minimum, and format code as code. (There is a lot of other things wrong with this question, do read the link I've sent above.)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it advisable to use GOTO Statement

No.  GOTO is an ancient and low-level flow control directive that should never be used unless there's no simpler flow control pattern available.

In practice, GOTO should never be needed since TRY/CATCH was added to TSQL.  It was necessary in earlier versions to jump to an error handler after checking [@@error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) after a statement, but is now all but obsolete.

The other place you occasionally saw GOTO was in a retry loop, but WHILE/BREAK now does a better job there.